# Deno: Disable warning logs (WARN) in console

Tags: deno

I'm new to Deno and I see that Deno is showing all warning logs (WARN) in the console.
Is there an option to disable this behavior?

UPDATE:
eventually, I think I need to be able to change the log level of Deno's default logger for its consoleHandler.
for example, when I'm using the Deno's fetch API, I don't want to see a lot of warnings about request/response size, etc.

Comment: What waring are you getting in the console, can you add some more info to question?

Comment: tnx for your comment, I updated the question.
I'm talking about all the warnings Deno is showing (at least for its standard library).

Answer (score 0):

There is *Fen* framework for deno that can do that: [here is link](https://deno.land/x/fen#logger)

Comment: tnx for your answer. but I need to change the log level in Deno's default logger for its standard library. I'm not using any other framework atm.